# The java code can compile in cmd window, but can not run in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cmd, java

## this is the code from TIJ4#

The java code can  compile and run in cmd window , but can not compile and run in **eclipse**  .

```
//: io/MemoryInput.java
import java.io.*;   

public class MemoryInput {
public static void main(String[] args)
throws IOException {
StringReader in = new StringReader(
    BufferedInputFile.read("MemoryInput.java"));
int c;
while((c = in.read()) != -1){
  System.out.print((char)c);
  }
}
```

the wrong information about the code in eclipse is :
*BufferedInputFile* cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedInputFile` is not part of the package `java.io`. If you have that class in a library or in a certain folder you have to include it in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you!you are right!i hava just figure out the problem .BufferedInputFile is defined by the author of the book

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedInputFile` is not part of any default lib of java. So you have to add that class to your class path.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i have find the reason ,and figure it out

Comment: You should update your pages more often. The (almost) exact same answer has been given by someone else one hour before yours.